# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' error when accessing web-api from angular2

Tags: asp.net-web-api, cors, angular2-services, accesscontrolexception

From one side I have an ASP.net web application that contains a web api module. 
On the same machine I have an angular 2 client application which is consuming the web api controllers crud methods. The angular 2 uses a basic http service with the uri of the localhost with the port number on which the web api runs on. I run the web api application and when the angular 2 tries to consume a Get request, I get this error message (22770 is the port of the web-api, 4200 is the port of the angular 2 application):

> Failed to load http://localhost:22770/api/: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access.

**Although this is quite a common question, mine is a little bit different:
CORS is defined as:
Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) is a mechanism that uses
additional HTTP headers to let a user agent gain permission to access
selected resources from a server on a different origin (domain) than
the site currently in use**

BUT - I'm working with the same domain - on my local machine (localhost).

What is the problem and how can I solve it ?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-web-api+cors?sort=votes

Comment: Take a look on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51144933/vs2017-web-application-cors-access-control-allow-origin/51157235#51157235), I got the same issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to enable CORS (cross origin request) in your web api. Follow instruction given in below page

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api

Answer (score 1):

OK - Investigated it a little bit and reached the reason for that error message when working on the same local host - It appears that a different port is considered as a different domain.
Exceptional addition I noticed:
"Internet Explorer does not consider the port when comparing origins"