# VS2017 Web application CORS: Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: c#, asp.net, angular, web-services, cors

I'm using `Angular 6+` for a small website presenting a `CRUD` to a `SQL Database`. I know `Angular` is a `client-side framework` so I have created a web service using `Visual Studio 2017` the project I used is a `web application ASP.NET Core` and since I'm testing it in a `localhost`, `Angular` runs over `4200 port` and my service is currently on `port 53819`

Due this, I have (or at last try) enabling `Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS)` by installing the CORS NUGget Package on my `webservice` and enabling it at controller level as shown:

```
...    
namespace CIE_webservice.Controllers
    {
        [Produces("application/json")]
        [Route("api/CIE")]
        [EnableCors(origins: "http://localhost:4200/", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
        public class CIEController : Controller
        {
            [HttpGet]
            public IEnumerable<string> Get()
            {
                return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
            }
...
```

on my `Angular App` I'm using a simple `ajax` request as follows:

```
$.ajax({
      url: 'http://localhost:53819/api/CIE/',
      success: function() {  console.log(" OK "); },
      error: function() {  console.log(" Error "); }
  });
```

As far as I can get the tutorials my code is OK but still getting the error:

```
Failed to load http://localhost:53819/api/CIE/: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Even tho the Ajax request has a response 200 OK and the preview shows me the response json:

[image]

Maybe I missed something or I'm not getting the concept well... If need more info to resolve my case feel free to ask.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is is it normal that you've hardcoded your CORS origin to a different port than the one you use on the client ?

Comment: @olleo I don't think it is normal but since is a localhost and initial config, well I just used like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on Glen's answer and this "[tutorial](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/How-to-enable-CORSCross-f87cd084)" I have managed to get the thing working.

On my `Startup.cs` file

```
...
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
  services.AddCors();       /* <----- Added this line before de MVC */
  services.AddMvc();
}
...
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env) {
  if (env.IsDevelopment()) {
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
  }
  app.UseCors(builder => builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200")); /* <----- Added this line before de MVC */
  app.UseMvc();
}
```

And in my controller file `CIEController.cs`

```
...    
namespace CIE_webservice.Controllers {
  [Produces("application/json")]
  [Route("api/CIE")]
  [EnableCors(origins: "http://localhost:4200/", headers: "*", methods: "*")] /* <--- This line remains here or can be added at the action level*/
  public class CIEController : Controller {
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<string> Get() {
      return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I have similar working in a hobby project, so I can show you what I did to get it working...

I did this in my Startup.cs

`app.UseCors(options => options.WithOrigins(Configuration["trustedCors"].Split(' ')).AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader());`

with this in my config file ...

"trustedCors": "http://localhost:60000 https://localhost:60000 http://glendesktop:60000 https://glendesktop:60000"

I also remember from my testing that case in important for CORS.

Comment: I have try written the line above and after `app.UseMvc();` but get the error: `System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.IConfiguration.this[string].get devolvió null.`